# How to test advanced interactions when developing an Alexa Skill

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I am developing an Alexa Skill, and I am struggling a bit in understanding if I setup everything in the best way possible to debug while developing.

Right now I am developing locally using Node.js, uploading to the cloud when ready, and testing all the responses to intents using the Service Simulator in the Test section of the developer console.
I find the process a bit slow but working... But still, I have two questions:

1) Is there a way of avoiding the process of uploading to the cloud?

And mostly important 2) How do I test advanced interactions, for examples multi-step ones, in the console? How for example to test triggering the response to an intent, but then asking the user for confirmation (Yes/No)? Right now the only way of doing it is using the actual device.

Any improvement is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'm testing multi-step interactions locally.

I'm using a 3rd party, free, tool called BSTAlexa:
http://docs.bespoken.tools/en/latest/api/classes/bstalexa.html

It emulates Amazon's role in accepting requests, feeding them to your skill, and maintaining the state of the interactions.

So I start my test script by configuring BSTAlexa - pointing it to my skill config (eg. intents) and to a local instance of my skill (in my case I'm giving it a local URL).

Then I feed BSTAlexa a sequence of textual requests and verify that I'm getting back the expected responses.  And I put all this in a Mocha script.

It works quite well.

Comment: Thanks, the bespoken tool is actually helping a lot... I am still struggling in testing multi-step interactions though, I have to understand how to run the test scripts

Answer (score 2):

Like @Tom suggested - take a look at bespoken.tools for testing skills locally.

Also, the [Alexa Command Line Interface](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/ask-cli-command-reference) was recently released and it has some command line options you might look into.

For example, the 'api invoke-skill' command lets you invoke the skill locally via the command line (or script) so you don't have to use the service simulator. Like this...

```
$ask api invoke-skill -s $SKILL_ID -f $JSON --endpoint-region $REGION --debug
```

Here is a quick video I did that introduces the ASK CLI. It doesn't specifically cover testing but it will provide a quick intro.

https://youtu.be/p-zlSdixCZ4

Hope that helps.

EDIT: Had another thought for testing locally. If you're using node and Lambda functions, you can call the index.js file from another local .js file (example: test.js) and pass in the event data and context. Here is an example:

```
//path to the Lambda index.js file
var lambdaFunction = require('../lambda/custom/index.js');

// json representing the event - just copy from the service simulator
var event = require('./events/GetUpdateByName.json');

var context = {
  'succeed': function (data) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null,'\t') );

  },
  'fail': function (err) {
      console.log('context.fail occurred');
      console.log(JSON.stringify(err, null,'\t') );
  }
};

function callback(error, data) {
  if(error) {
      console.log('error: ' + error);
  } else {
      console.log(data);
  }
}

// call the lambda function
lambdaFunction.handler (event, context, callback);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find answers (Answering in reverse order),

2. You can test multiple steps using simulator (echosim.io) but each time you have to press and hold Mic button (Or hold on space bar). Say for example first you are asking something to Alexa with echosim and alexa responding to confirm'yes/no' then you have to press and hold mic button again to respond to confirm it.
3. You can automate the lambda deployment process. Please see the link,
   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/automating-deployment.html

It would be good to write complete unit tests so that you can test your logic before uploading Lambda. Also it will help to reduce the number of Lambda deployments